# How to prevent Firefox to expand a mouse hovered DOM node in the developer-tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

The "pick an element from the page" feature in Firefox developpers tools allows to visualy click on an element to reveal it in the DOM tree view.

But as the mouse hovers different elements, each of them are being expanded in the DOM tree view.

Is it possible to disable that feature, so the tree view stays clean and collapsed (or expanded) to only the elements that have previously been selected?

Note: clicking on an element should expand the tree to reveal that element, it's only the hovering consequences that I wish to disable.

Comment: Good observation. Right click - inspect only expands what you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is currently no way to change that behavior.
Though I agree that it is probably not what users expect, therefore I've created [bug 1316528](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1316528) asking to collapse the tree again when hovering another element.

Comment: Thank you, I will comment on the bugzilla issue.